# QGIS3: Import csv_file with DateTime Values

Tags: qgis, csv, import, datetime

Has anyone managed to read in a "DateTime" value yet? I do not succeed, I always get text values.

**Test1**

```
point_id,X,Y,ele,time,Ds,len
"371",676239.6644,212505.7907,486,2020/04/07 09:58:07,0,0
"372",676238.6797,212497.3033,486.2,2020/04/07 09:58:08,8.544,8.54
```

**Test2**

```
point_id,X,Y,ele,time,Ds,len
"371",676239.6644,212505.7907,486,2020-04-07T09:58:07.000,0,0
"372",676238.6797,212497.3033,486.2,2020-04-07T09:58:08.000,8.544,8.54
```

**Settings**
Almost all default:
[image]

**Result**
"time" is always of the "text" type
[image]

I also experimented with csvt - no success.
What am I doing wrong?

My System
Win 10 pro 64 bit German
QGIS 3.10.2

Comment: Maybe you need to open a bug issue within QGIS

Comment: Already a bug in fact https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/20882. I've asked to reopen.

Comment: Followup: solved in QGIS. Need to wait to see the fix in your QGIS binary https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/37081 PS: not aware of backporting strategy so does not know in which version(s) of QGIS the fix will land: only latest or previous version(s) or both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to use a csvt file (like documented at https://anitagraser.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/) to force the type when adding "Delimited text layer". If I tick the "Detect field types" or not, I get the same issue as you: no clues why too...

To get what I want, I have to go another way.

I create your sample file "test1.csv" with

```
point_id,X,Y,ele,time,Ds,len
"371",676239.6644,212505.7907,486,2020/04/07 09:58:07,0,0
"372",676238.6797,212497.3033,486.2,2020/04/07 09:58:08,8.544,8.54
```

Then, I create a "test1.csvt" with

```
"Integer","Real","Real","Real","DateTime","Real","Real"
```

For where DateTime comes from, see [OGR CSV Driver documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/csv.html)

Then, I create a vrt file "test1.vrt"

```xml
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="test1">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">test1.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="X" y="Y"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

I finish by using in the menu the "Add Vector Layer..." instead of "Add Delimited Text Layer...". In this menu, I choose to open "test1.vrt" and now it works (below screenshot).

[image: test1.vrt screenshot properties panel]

Alternate solution I could call "Full vrt" could be to delete/throw away the `test1.csvt` and use an alternate `test1.vrt` to also declare the field types to use like below

```xml
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="test1">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">test1.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
        <Field name="point_id" type="Integer"/>
        <Field name="X" type="Real"/> <!--Can be remove if you only want X for the geometry-->
        <Field name="Y" type="Real"/> <!--Can be remove if you only want Y for the geometry-->
        <Field name="ele" type="Real"/>
        <Field name="time" type="DateTime"/>
        <Field name="Ds" type="Real"/>
        <Field name="len" type="Real"/>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="X" y="Y"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

VRT vector can do much more like abstracting original layer structure to rename columns and much more (outside the scope of the answer). Look at https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/vrt.html to learn more.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. This version works perfectly. I just had to replace "WGS84" with "EPSG:31259".